# Executing script inserted with innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm using the following code to attempt to execute one of adNetworks banners after an innerhtml has been called

```
   // container is where you want the ad to be inserted
var container = document.getElementById('sponsor_container2');
var w = document.write;
document.write = function (content) {
    container.innerHTML = content;
    document.write = w;
};
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.src = 'http://go.adversal.com/ttj?id=2609728&size=728x90&promo_sizes=468x60,320x50,300x50,216x36';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

However for whatever reason I reason the following message

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=2609728&size=728x90&promo_sizes=468x60,320x50,300x50,216x36".
```

And nothing happens, the above code has worked in the past for previous adNetworks so this is why I'm so dumb founded

This is the script my ad page provided me

```
<script src="http://go.adversal.com/ttj?id=2609728&size=728x90&promo_sizes=468x60,320x50,300x50,216x36" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: the script uses document.write(), which you break.

Comment: All ads use document.write, my method has never broke them before switching to this network. This is a simple override so that the script is usually executed

Answer (score 0):

**I think your problem is the fact that you have re-defined a function that is already in the Javascript document notation**: `document.write()` is a function that is used to write to the document, and as you may know, you cannot re-define defined functions in Javascript.

You probably just want `document.write(w)` or something like that.

Hope I could help.

Comment: I've redefined it here as when previous networks loaded their ads using the write function, I could then direct it to the exact div where I wanted it to write and actually have them load. 

Without it the script isn't executed at all when you send it via innerhtml

Comment: Interesting, have you tried the jQuery library? That could simplify things, also inside the redefined function, and your defining of the variable 'w', your syntax for document.write isn't right. As far as I know, you always need the parentheses, forgive me if I'm wrong. @user3037561

Comment: Is there a specific Jquery library for this? I just never though it could be so difficult to execute a script tag dynamically lol

Comment: jQuery's $(elm).html(str) WILL execute script tags, unlike elm.innerHTML=str; you can also simply eval() the textContent of the script tag to accomplish the same thing.